# What is the mantra for cupid Kam Deva?

Tags: vedas, mantras

I have heard that Kam Deva's mantra is very effective to attract anybody in this world. What is that Mantra?

Is it this mantra?

> ઓમ નમો ભગવતે કામદેવાય યશ્ય યશ્ય દ્રશ્યો ભવામિ । યશ્ય યશ્ય મમ્ સુખં પશ્યતિ તં તં મોહયતુ સ્વાહા ।।
>
> om namo bhagawate kamdevay yashya yashya drashyo bhavami| Yashya Yashya Mam sukham tam tam Mohyatu Svaha ||

Comment: ॐ कामदेवाय काम वशं कराय अमुकस्य हृदयं स्तम्भय स्तम्भय मोहय मोहय वशमानय स्वाहा ॥  i get from this site http://www.gurushakti.org.in/5/sadhna/vashikaran-kamdev-mantra

Comment: is this mantra from vedas?

Comment: this mantra is for atract some one written in mention site , dont know about is from vedas or not , and from where you get this mantra  ઓમ નમો ભગવતે કામદેવાય યશ્ય યશ્ય દ્રશ્યો ભવામિ । યશ્ય યશ્ય મમ્ સુખં પશ્યતિ તં તં મોહયતુ સ્વાહા ।

Comment: from news site http://navgujaratsamay.indiatimes.com/photo-mazza/kamdev-vashikaran-mantra/-/photoshow/48884190.cms

Comment: Mantras are to be treated reverentially and obtained from a learned guru alone. They should neither be given nor taken nor recited publically.

Comment: Be Practical. It is not rigid thing.

Comment: @BhavinPatel, what you wrote as the 1st comment should be an answer, irrespective of whether it works or not!

Comment: @iammilind but i can't find which our scripture mention this shloka, thats why I can not  posting as a answer

Comment: Who says it is not rigid? Sastra is always rigid. We do not have the authority to dilute it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kAmadeva or ananga is the deity of love, attraction, desire etc. There are many variants of the mantra available. 
The use of the mantra is not limited to attracting opposite gender but also for materializing the materialistic desires of life and creativity.

> The name is used in Rig Veda (RV 9, 113. 11).[3] Kamadeva is a name of
>   Vishnu in Vishnu Purana and Bhagavata Purana (SB 5.18.15), and of
>   Krishna as well as Shiva. Kama is also a name used for Agni (Atharva
>   Veda 6.36.3).
>
> Other names used in reference to Kamadeva are Manmatha/Manmathudu (one
>   who agitates), Atanu (one without a body), Ragavrinta (stalk of
>   passion), Ananga (incorporeal), Kandarpa (inflamer even of a god),
>   Madana(intoxicating),[3][4] "Manmatha" मन्मथ (churner of hearts),
>   Manasija {he who is born of mind}, a contraction of the Sanskrit
>   phrase Sah Manasah jāta), Ratikānta (lord of Rati), Pushpavān,
>   Pushpadhanva, Kusumashara कुसुमशर (one with arrow of flowers),
>   Abhipura (also a name for both Shiva and Vishnu[5]), and simply Kāma
>   (desire, longing). ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamadeva))

**Manmatha Gayatri Mantra**

> om kAma-devAya vidmahe
>
> puShpa-vANAya dhImahe
>
> tanno kAma prachodayAt
>
> Om, Let me meditate on the God of love, One with flower-arrows
>   (kAma-deva), give me higher intellect, And let the God of love
>   illuminate my mind.

[Source](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Gayatri_mantras_of_Several_Gods)